# How to get sum of records of female candidate whose age is less than 50 using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have two table Candidates and Results and I also attached the screen shots of these two tables I want to get sum of votes of Female candidates whose age is less than 50.

I am a bit new to databases.

[[image: Results Table][1]]

And this is candidates table:

[image]

```
 SELECT Results.candidate_id, Candidates.gender, Candidates.age, 
  FROM Results
  INNER JOIN Candidates
  ON Results.candidate_id=Candidates.id;
```

Comment: Can you show what you've been able to get going? Also, you tagged with order-by but don't mention ordering in your question; missing something?

Comment: All you need is a WHERE clause and SUM.

Comment: You need a `where` clause to filter down to females younger than 50 then sum() on their votes.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(votes) total_votes
FROM results r
INNER JOIN candidates c 
    ON c.id = r.candidate_id 
    AND c.gender = 'F'
    AND c.age < 50
```

You might want to change `<` to `<=`, depending on what you mean by *less than* 50 years old.